# how to write in a QTableView when a radiobutton is selected ? [PyQt5]

Tags: python, pyqt5

I'm working on a GUI with radio buttons and QTableView. (here is a screenshot ) [image]

I want to show in the QTableview at left a dataframe when "toutes les stations de références" are selected.

here is what I already wrote :

```py
from GUI_ui import Ui_MainWindow
from connect_phyc_ui import Ui_Dialog_connect_phyc
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets as qtw
from PyQt5 import QtCore
import sys
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 

class df_seuil(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel): #this work when used as MainWindow
    def __init__(self, data):
        QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self)
        self._data=data

    def rowCount(self, parent=None):
        return self._data.shape[0]
    
    def columnCount(self,parent=None):
        return self._data.shape[1]
    
    def data(self, index,role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole) : 
        if index.isValid():
            if role==Qt.displayRole:
                return str(self._data.iloc[index.row(), index.column()])

            return None

    def headerData(self,col,orientation,role):
        if orientation == QtCore.Qt.Horizontal and role ==QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            return self.data.columns[col]
        return None


class MainWindow(qtw.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self,data):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        '''
        Some code 
        '''     
        self.tableview_input.connect(self.list_station)
 
     def list_station(self,data) : 
        if self.all_ref_station_radioButton.isChecked() == True :
            data=pd.DataFrame(data["Code_Station"])
            self.model=df_seuil(data)
            self.tableview_input.setModel(self.model)
        if self.select_tron_radioButton.isChecked() == True :
            data=pd.DataFrame(set(data["Tronçon"]))
            self.model=df_seuil(data)
            self.tableview_input.setModel(self.model)
        if self.selecBV_radioButton.isChecked()== True : 
            data=pd.DataFrame(set(data["Cours_d_Eau"]))
            self.model=df_seuil(data)
            self.tableview_input.setModel(self.model)

    def my_excepthook(etype, value, tback):
        """Called when an error is raised to stop PyQt5 crashing"""

        print(value)

        sys.__excepthook__(etype, value, tback)
    
    sys.excepthook = my_excepthook


data=pd.read_excel("seuils.xlsx")
data=pd.DataFrame(data)      

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = qtw.QApplication(sys.argv)
    data=data

    main = MainWindow(data)
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I havn't any idea how to link df_seuil to MainWindow, so if you can help me !
Thank you !
EDIT : I actualized my code.
to explain it a bit more : I want the QTableView Content to change in function of the radiobutton.
I succeeded in writing something in the QTableView, but I'm still looking for a way to change what is showed in function of the radiobutton selected.

Comment: Yout question is really confusing. While what you want to achieve is almost clear, the code is not. Why do are you trying to subclass MainWindow from `df_seuil`? Not only it doesn't make any sense (df_seuil is a model, an abstract representation of data, while QMainWindow is a *widget* a graphical interface, they are two completely different things), but it may cause serious issues and possibly even crash.

Comment: I wrote this because a guy said me I should call ```df_seuil``` in my MainWindow I still don't understand why. Now I succeeded in writing something and I actualized my code. I didn't find an alternative to ```connect()``` for QTableView.. (when I use it I have an error  ``` AttributeError: 'QTableView' object has no attribute 'connect'```

Comment: The term "call" is a bit vague. Maybe, they intended that you should create an instance of that class, which is achieve doing something like `self.model = df_seuil()` ("calling" a class returns a new instance of that class). Then, using the `connect` method of Qt objects is obsolete (and no more supported), you are probably going to connect some signal, but since it's not clear what you need to do it's a bit hard to help you. From what I can read, I suspect that you don't really know what signals and slots are and how they work, so I suggest you to do some research on the subject first.

Comment: Do you know where I can see the differents method to connect a QTableView ? Sorry for the vague term,  I'm not very fluent in english so maybe I'm not using the right term. I'll try to explain what I need to do better. I want to "refresh" the QTableView in function of which radiobutton is checked. So when I select a radiobutton, it emit a signal, and I want to connect it to "list_seuil"